# How to capture rejected records in SAP BODS?

Tags: error-logging, sap-data-services

I am doing a lookup operation in BODS. The records that match need to be sent to a table and the ones that don't match need to be captured in a file.

Can you please help me out on how to capture the records that failed the lookup?

It was easy in IBM Datastage but in SAP BODS it's quite complex.

Answer (score -2):

Look up is like a left Outer Join, it returns null for the non matching column from the right side table.

If you are matching records from Table A by doing look up to Table B, you must be fetching fields from Table B as well,

If the records are matching they will have values from table B, and those that doe not match will end having NULL values for Table B columns,
after separate the data with 2 Query transforms

```
**1) where Table B col is not null and load to the desired table 
2) where Table B col is null and load Flat File.**
```

Comment: "Can you please help me out on how to capture the records that failed the lookup?" How your answer relates to the question?